# Cakephp3.0 I am calling Postcategories controller into Appcontroller and it is error " Call to undefined method Cake\Core\App::import() "

Tags: cakephp, controller, cakephp-3.0

My Code tries to fetch all Main categories of the posts into Appcontroller  to show on the homepage:

```
namespace App\Controller;
use Cake\Core\App;
use Cake\Controller\Controller;
class AppController extends Controller
{
 public $helpers = ['Html', 'Form', 'Session','Time','Tree'];


public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    $this->maincategories();
}

function maincategories(){
    App::import('Controller','Postcategories');
    $postcates = new PostcategoriesController;
    $postcates = $postcategory->find('threaded');

}

}
```

Comment: I would reccomend you to use a cell.

Comment: I would recommend to not use `App::import()` in Cake3, it was already deprecated in Cake2 and should always have been replaced by App::uses() there. In 3.x it is now "use ..." statements.

Answer (score 4):

Your `maincategories()` method is wrong. You need the model, not the controller to retrieve the data from. You need to use `TableRegistry::get('Postcategories')` to get the `Postcategories` model and then call the find on that:-

```
public function maincategories()
{
    $Postcategories = TableRegistry::get('Postcategories');
    $this->set('postcategories', $Postcategories->find('threaded'));
}
```

`$this->set()` is setting the categories as a view variable (`$postcategories`). You will need to make sure you include `use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;` at the top of your AppController file.

Make sure you've fully read the [docs on retrieving data](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html).

Comment: Other points: initialize is called from the construtor - it is not a good idea to call anything like this in initialize (and since XsController extends app controller - it's a loop). It should be called from beforeRender, if necessary. Also, at the risk of trying to run before being able to crawl, there's no need to hit the db on each request for data that doesn't change, [Cache::remember](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html#read-through-caching) is one way to avoid that. +1.

Comment: Absolutely worked, Thanks Ninja. You were right I didnt read carefully the 3.X docs for retrieving data.

Comment: @Chirayubhatt glad it worked. Please accept my answer so that others know that this works. :-)